# Is it possible to render unity asset in react native with a transparent background ? ( interacting with RN app while having a 3d unity character )

Tags: swift, react-native, unity-game-engine

using react-native-unity or other library, is it possible to make the unity view background transparent and click-through, making it possible to interact with the underlaying react native app?

tried react-native-unity and managed to get a mini game running but could not make background transparent / click through